# Can't get section divs together

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to the world of html and I'm learning it from a book and youtube.

I'm trying to create this one page design.
[This one right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nK156.jpg)

I started out with only the html and got some lorem ipsum in to check where I'm at. All was well..

But then I started trying to get the sections in to shape and getting them to stick together, but that is where it all went wrong. And I cant figure out what the problem is! (except for me being a pro newbie of course)

[This is where im at in js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Burner/k96ja4p9/3/)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC);
 * {
  color: white;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
section {} h1 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 800%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}
h3 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  font-size: 300%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}
#home {
  background-color: #334960;
}
#about {
  background-color: #f17c72;
}
#portfolio {
  background-color: #32ac97;
}
#contact {
  background-color: #7f4c75;
}
#blog {
  background-color: #3f9fc9;
}
footer {
  background-color: #334960;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section id="home">
    <!-- Home section -->
    <h1>My name</h1>
    <h3>Someday i will be a front end developer</h3>
  </section>

  <section id="about">
    <!-- About section -->
    <h1>About</h1>
    <aside>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x450">
    </aside>
    <article id="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla porta diam ante, eu vestibulum risus vestibulum id. Curabitur sed est arcu. Sed auctor ornare eros, ut vulputate felis tempor sit amet. Donec egestas turpis at quam vestibulum, non varius
      augue finibus. Curabitur eu tellus id lectus porttitor pretium quis vitae massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut ante diam, feugiat pharetra imperdiet eu, finibus in purus. Sed dapibus
      quam ut efficitur euismod. Nunc vel urna sem. Integer id massa euismod, iaculis sem eget, congue enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque pretium urna a magna suscipit, in semper ex
      euismod. Nullam sit amet quam auctor, viverra tellus non, imperdiet magna. Integer ante massa, sollicitudin et metus ac, dictum iaculis nisl. Fusce urna velit, sagittis quis lorem quis, fermentum mollis nulla.</article>
  </section>

  <section id="portfolio">
    <!-- Portfolio section -->
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
    <article id="left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </article>
    <article id="mid">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </article>
    <article id="right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </article>
    <!-- row -->
    <article id="left">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </article>
    <article id="mid">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </article>
    <article id="right">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </article>
    <!-- row -->
  </section>

  <section id="contact">
    <!-- Contact section -->
    <h1>Contact</h1>
    <article id="contactform">
      <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Voor en achternaam:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Telefoonnummer:</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>E-mail Adres:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Uw bericht:</label>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your message" maxlength="999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="success"></div>
        <!-- For success/fail messages -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Verstuur</button>
      </form>
    </article>
  </section>

  <section id="blog">
    <!-- Blog section -->
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <blog>
      <h2 class="blogtitle">Blog title</h2>
      <p class="blogtitlesub">By admin</p>
      <p>Integer facilisis at dolor eu accumsan. Quisque sollicitudin sem justo, a blandit sem accumsan non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis dui libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur tincidunt metus
        sed leo facilisis venenatis quis sit amet mi. Nullam sed ipsum mi. Quisque sapien turpis, porttitor eget ornare vitae, vestibulum vel enim. Fusce quis porta justo, vel sodales nisl. Sed feugiat, turpis suscipit sollicitudin convallis, diam neque
        tempor nunc, sed dapibus orci odio id felis. Donec nisl erat, lacinia eu ipsum non, dictum accumsan augue. Vivamus eu justo facilisis, semper elit nec, blandit sem. Nam suscipit eu sem vitae ornare. Integer a nisi non risus dictum porta quis sed
        massa. Nulla facilisi.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </blog>
    <hr>
    <blog>
      <h2 class="blogtitle">Blog title</h2>
      <p class="blogtitlesub">By admin</p>
      <p>Integer facilisis at dolor eu accumsan. Quisque sollicitudin sem justo, a blandit sem accumsan non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis dui libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur tincidunt metus
        sed leo facilisis venenatis quis sit amet mi. Nullam sed ipsum mi. Quisque sapien turpis, porttitor eget ornare vitae, vestibulum vel enim. Fusce quis porta justo, vel sodales nisl. Sed feugiat, turpis suscipit sollicitudin convallis, diam neque
        tempor nunc, sed dapibus orci odio id felis. Donec nisl erat, lacinia eu ipsum non, dictum accumsan augue. Vivamus eu justo facilisis, semper elit nec, blandit sem. Nam suscipit eu sem vitae ornare. Integer a nisi non risus dictum porta quis sed
        massa. Nulla facilisi.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </blog>
    <hr>
    <blog>
      <h2 class="blogtitle">Blog title</h2>
      <p class="blogtitlesub">By admin</p>
      <p>Integer facilisis at dolor eu accumsan. Quisque sollicitudin sem justo, a blandit sem accumsan non. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis dui libero. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur tincidunt metus
        sed leo facilisis venenatis quis sit amet mi. Nullam sed ipsum mi. Quisque sapien turpis, porttitor eget ornare vitae, vestibulum vel enim. Fusce quis porta justo, vel sodales nisl. Sed feugiat, turpis suscipit sollicitudin convallis, diam neque
        tempor nunc, sed dapibus orci odio id felis. Donec nisl erat, lacinia eu ipsum non, dictum accumsan augue. Vivamus eu justo facilisis, semper elit nec, blandit sem. Nam suscipit eu sem vitae ornare. Integer a nisi non risus dictum porta quis sed
        massa. Nulla facilisi.</p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </blog>
    <hr>
  </section>

  <footer>
    Copyright by ME</footer>
</div>
```

What could it be the issue?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of your desired output.

Comment: there is a link "This one right here". Wich leads to my design.

Answer (score 1):

Set h1 and h3 to `margin:0;` You have the default margins for the h tags and doing this would reset them.

Comment: Be aware that any other element in your `section` with inappropriate `margin` can cause this behavior too. Also resetting the `margin` of `h1` and `h3` may lead to unwanted design results.

Comment: Obviously just for the sections needed, with specificity, like #container h1.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of your `<h1>` tags.
When your browser parse a `<h*>` tag it generally add a margin at the top and the bottom of the title. It's a default behaviour of many browers.
You had already set `margin-bottom` to 0, so you just have to do the same `margin-top` :

```
h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```